# How to install a specific patch version of postgresql-client with apt?

Tags: postgresql, apt

If I run the following command, it will install version 9.6.2 but I want 9.6.1:

```
apt-get install postgresql-client-9.6
```

Is this possible?

## Update 1

I am trying to do this in a `Dockerfile` like so:

```
FROM ruby:2.2.5

# Add source for Postgres 9.6
RUN echo 'deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ jessie-pgdg main' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/postgresql.list
RUN wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | apt-key add -

RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential
 
# for postgres
RUN apt-get install -y libpq-dev postgresql-client-9.6
```

Comment: You can download it from here http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/pool/9.6/p/postgresql-9.6/ with wget and then run `dpkg -i filename` If it fits I will add it as an answer.

Comment: @JorgeCampos I only see the release candidates listed there, not version 9.6.1

Comment: What is your distro and which version?

Comment: I am trying to install this in a `Dockerfile` based on the `ruby:2.2.5` image which itself is based on `jessie`.

Comment: @JorgeCampos I have updated my post with the relevant parts of my `Dockerfile`

Comment: Sorry, couldn't find another link. :(